# How to select ids in stored procedure and update some columns using that ids at once and return the ids?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The problem that I am facing is how to store the result of select query in a variable in the stored procedure to perform the update and then return the variable as result.

Comment: so is it oracle or MySQL ? please fix your tags. you could use a cursor as a select query and then loop through the results and perform your updates.... if I understood you currently...

Comment: Why do you have a SELECT if what you actually want is an UPDATE?

Comment: I tagged oracle because this problem has the same solution in oracle or in mysql and my aim is to select and update at once so that same result doesn't appear again when i hit the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE PROCEDURE `getOrderForMarketBuyExecution`(OUT response text)
BEGIN
SET @uids := 0;
UPDATE test SET processing = true WHERE id IN (SELECT t.id from test WHERE processing = false) AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', id, @uids) );
set response = @uids;
END

Answer (score 0):

More or less exactly as you explained in plain English; just convert it to code. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number, par_var out number
  2  is
  3    l_maxsal number;
  4  begin
  5    -- store result of SELECT into a variable
  6    select max(sal)
  7      into l_maxsal
  8      from emp
  9      where deptno = par_deptno;
 10
 11    -- perform UPDATE
 12    update emp set
 13      sal = l_maxsal
 14      where deptno = par_deptno;
 15
 16    -- return its value
 17    par_var := l_maxsal;
 18  end;
 19  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing: initial table contents:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, sal from emp where deptno = 10;

    DEPTNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
        10 CLARK            2450
        10 KING             5001
        10 MILLER           1300
```

Calling the procedure; as it returns an `OUT` parameter, you have to declare a variable which will accept it:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_var number;
  3  begin
  4    p_test(par_deptno => 10, par_var => l_var);
  5    dbms_output.put_line('Procedure returned ' || l_var);
  6  end;
  7  /
Procedure returned 5001

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, sal from emp where deptno = 10;

    DEPTNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
        10 CLARK            5001
        10 KING             5001
        10 MILLER           5001

SQL>
```

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN 
SET @ids = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.id) from test t WHERE processing = false);
UPDATE test SET processing = true WHERE id IN (@ids);
set response = @ids;
END;

Comment: That's not Oracle. My code is. You tagged the question as "Oracle" (among other tags).